NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '...' not found. '...' is not a valid view function or pattern name - for path include name
I have this setup:
# Django Project: core/urls.py
def redirect_index(request):
    return redirect(reverse('account'), permanent=False)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', redirect_index, name='index'),
    path('account/', include('identity.urls'), name='account'),
]

# Django App: identity/urls.py
app_name = 'identity'

def redirect_index(request):
    return redirect(reverse('identity:login'), permanent=False)

def view_login(request):
    context = {"test_context": 'This is a test context'}
    return render(request, "common/base.html", context)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', redirect_index, name='index'),
    path('login', view_login, name='login'),
]

When I visit http://localhost:8000/, I get this error:
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'account' not found. 'account' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

What I want is this:
If user goes to /, it should redirect to /account/, and from there redirect to /account/login. I know there are 2 redirects, but I'd like to have them separate so that I can set each one separately. But I get the above error. It looks like when there is an include, the name cannot be reversed.
Of course, when I use reverse('identity:index') or reverse('identity:login') instead of reverse('account') in core/urls.py, it works.
Is there no way I can do it the way I described earlier?

reverse('identity:index') does exactly what you want to do (You just don't see that URL because your browser redirects you quite quickly), why do you specifically want to write reverse('account')?

It doesn't matter to me if I don't see the redirecting URL on the browser. Its just that using account seems much more intuitive, as it is the name of the path for the include('core/urls'). If I had multiple includes, it'd be very clear.

But include('identity.urls') includes a set of urls (In fact an include doesn't need to and shouldn't have a name), what you say is intuitive is ambiguous to me.

But, account/ in core.urls.urlpatterns will resolve to '' in identity.urls.urlpatterns anyway.
